# Why chrome loads javascript function much slower than firefox?

Tags: javascript, performance, loading

do you have any idea why chrome loads javascript function much slower than firefox?
In firefox it only takes 2 seconds. But in chrome, it took more than 5 or 6 seconds. What could be the reason?

This is the extra specific javascript code

```
$('.addtoplaylist-video').on('click', function(){
    $(this).css({'display':'none'});
    $(this).parent('.toggle,.toggle2')
        .find('.viewplaylist-video')
        .css({'display':'block'});
});



$('.viewplaylist-video').on('click', function(){
    $(this).css({'display':'none'});
    $(this).parent('.toggle, .toggle2')
        .find('.addtoplaylist-video')
        .css({'display':'block'});
});

$('.link-add').on('click', function(){
    $(this).css({'display':'none'});
    $(this).parent('.hovervideoplaylist')
        .find('.link-viewplaylist')
        .css({'display':'block'});

});


$('.link-viewplaylist').on('click', function(){
    $(this).css({'display':'none'});
    $(this).parent('.hovervideoplaylist')
        .find('.link-add')
        .css({'display':'block'});
});
```

Comment: You're saying it takes 6 seconds to load those 30 lines of code ?

Comment: I very much doubt either Firefox or Chrome takes more than a couple of milliseconds to "load" that code. Do you mean an external file? When are you measuring from? Have you measured multiple times, methodically? What other things are happening on your network? Is this over the internet with its wildly-varying characteristics?